# Checking login details using c#.net

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, syntax-error, adapter

I am getting an error:

> cannot convert from MySql.Data.MysqlClient.MySqlCommand to
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' at SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

```
string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=smsjobs;Uid=root;pwd=root;";

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd; connection.Open();
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText="select * from userdetails where db_mobi=@username and db_pass=@word";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", cn_mobi.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", cn_pass.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);// getting error here 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["id"] = cn_mobi.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Redirectform.aspx");
        Session.RemoveAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot convert from MySql.Data.MysqlClient.MySqlCommand to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' at  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

Comment: try setting  sda.selectcommand=cmd;

Comment: You should probably use `MySqlDataAdapter`, since `SqlDataAdapter` is for SQL server, not MySQL.

Comment: SqlDataAdapter expects SqlCommand, so create object of that instead of MySqlCommand

Comment: @adil ...but only if you're connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server, and not a MySQL server

Comment: Yes definitely, @RowlandShaw, thanks for clarifying though.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make SqlDataAdapter (the one for MS SQL) working with MySqlCommand. There is a [MySqlDataAdapter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-data-adapter.html), so looks like you need to be using it instead.
But anyway, this code makes no sense:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);// getting error here 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You're calling DataAdapter to fill DataTable via SqlCommand, and then call that SqlCommand again with ExecuteNonQuery. That`s totally nonsense.
You need to change your code to this (probably):

```
string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=smsjobs;Uid=root;pwd=root;";

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString)) {
        connection.Open(); 
        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText="select * from userdetails where db_mobi=@username and db_pass=@word";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", cn_mobi.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", cn_pass.Text);

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Session["id"] = cn_mobi.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Redirectform.aspx");
            Session.RemoveAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `using` instead of direct `connection.Close()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `System.Data.OleDb;`namespace and in that namespace you have same classes. Means instead of `SqlConnection` you should use `OleDbConnection` and in place of `SqlDataAdapter` you can use `OleDbDataAdapter`.

I think it should work. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

to

```
 MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter (cmd);
```

Since SqlDataAdapter is not going to be overloaded with MySqlCommand.